# GH pages is not seeing the path to my images

Tags: css, angularjs, github-pages

```
GET http://kbazl3.github.io/style/icons/wind.png 404 (Not Found)
night.png:1 
GET http://kbazl3.github.io/style/icons/night.png 404 (Not Found)
/style/icons/cloudy.png:1 
GET http://kbazl3.github.io/style/icons/cloudy.png 404 (Not Found)
rain.png:1 
GET http://kbazl3.github.io/style/icons/rain.png 404 (Not Found)
alert.png:1 
GET http://kbazl3.github.io/style/icons/alert.png 404 (Not Found)
```

I'm getting these errors on my gh-pages found here: http://kbazl3.github.io/RainCheck/#/
It works just fine on my local live-server

here is the link to my source code: https://github.com/kbazl3/RainCheck/tree/gh-pages

I've looked up numerous other SO questions where others were having the same issue and it always came down to case sensitivity.  I'v quadruple and quintuple checked my case sensitivity from my file path and it's all identical. I cannot find ANY discrepancies.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  My file path is found in my weatherService:

```
//SET CURRENT WEATHER ICONS AND ROUTES
            if (cityObj.icon === "clear-day") {
                cityObj.icon = "clear";
                cityObj.img = "/style/icons/clear.png";
            } else if (cityObj.icon === "partly-cloudy-day") {
                cityObj.icon = "clear";
                cityObj.img = "/style/icons/cloudy.png";
            } else if (cityObj.icon === "rain" || cityObj.icon === "sleet" || cityObj.icon === "hail" || cityObj.icon === "thunderstorm" || cityObj.icon === "tornado") {
                cityObj.icon = "rainy";
                cityObj.img = "/style/icons/rain.png";
            } else if (cityObj.icon === "cloudy") {
                cityObj.icon = "cloudy";
                cityObj.img = "/style/icons/cloudy.png";
            } else if (cityObj.icon === "snow") {
                cityObj.icon = "snowy";
                cityObj.img = "/style/icons/snow.png";
            } else if (cityObj.icon === "clear-night" || cityObj.icon ===   "partly-cloudy-night") {
                cityObj.icon = "clearNight";
                cityObj.img = "/style/icons/night.png";
            } else if (cityObj.icon === "wind") {
                cityObj.icon = "windy";
                cityObj.img = "/style/icons/wind.png";
            } else if (cityObj.icon === "fog") {
                cityObj.icon = "cloudy";
                cityObj.img = "/style/icons/fog.png";
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need `RainCheck` in the paths, like this: `http://kbazl3.github.io/RainCheck/style/icons/wind.png`.

Since your homepage is `http://kbazl3.github.io/RainCheck`, a relative path would also work: `style/icons/wind.png`.

Comment: Thanks a ton Ben! Worked like a charm.  instead of doing it the 2 ways your recommended above, could I also write out the path like ./style/icons/wind.png?

Comment: Yup, that should work as well, assuming you're in the top-level `RainCheck` directory.